# Document Detection via Open CV Swift

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, image-scanner

I am working on document scanning and I am thinking to use open CV to scan the document and capture it in iOS.

I was checking out one [Github project](https://github.com/yushulx/ios-document-scanner/tree/master/docscanner) which is providing me the same concept but, I want to customise it and perform it as per the project requirement so wanted to do from scratch by myself.

Can somebody suggest me, from where to start or any recommendation to scan a document?

I have seen OpenCV portal, but it all talked about face detection, object detection.